# Convert String timestamp to total minutes

Tags: scala

I have a Unix timestamp as String and I would like to extract hour and minutes in order to convert this timestamp into total minutes.

```
val timestamp = "1469768809"
```

It would be straightforward if `timestamp` were not String (i.e. using `timestamp.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)`). However I don't know how to deal with a String.

Comment: You want unix epoch in milliseconds to epoch in minutes?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have epoch time in seconds. Convert the string to an `Int`, then do the necessary calculation:

```
val minutes = "1469768809".toInt / 60
```

Unless what you actually want is a datetime, in which case you should look into some of the date/time libraries for scala, e.g. [nscala-time](https://github.com/nscala-time/nscala-time)